# how create websocket and xpages server side

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

Simeone have suggest to create html5 websocket feature into xpages server side?
It's very import for notification feature.
Tnx to all

Answer (score 0):

Domino doesn't support Websocket (it appeared in later version of various servlet containers, though not in Domino). What you can do though is to write your own websocket server which runs inside Domino. See http://www.mindoo.com/web/blog.nsf/dx/03.11.2012141402KLEHJC.htm?opendocument&comments on how FTP server was implemented. I think you can use it as a guidance.

For example http://java-websocket.org/ it's open source and I guess it shouldn't be hard to adapt it for Domino.

PS: Alternative way: contact IBM and ask them to implement it.